# Multiple filter and sort in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery functions that work fine individually. Function A below, shows all, complete, incomplete items depending on the selection and it works fine. Function B show items according to the category(option) they belong to.

I now want to combine the two so that the filter works in this manner. User selects function B and selects the option and then the user can further refine, to see all items, completed or incomplete items only in the selected option.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4H66K/7/)

Function A:

```js
$('.sort').click(function(){
        var _t=$(this);
        $('.sort').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if(_t.hasClass('showall')){
            $('li.todo').show();
        }else if(_t.hasClass('complete')){
            $('li.todo').show();
            $('li.todo').filter(function(){
                return !!$(this).find('span.uncheck_box').length;
            }).hide();
        }else if(_t.hasClass('incomplete')){
            $('li.todo').show();
            $('li.todo').filter(function(){
                return !!$(this).find('span.check_box').length;
            }).hide();
        }

    });
```

Function B (dropdown):

```js
$('.itemage').change(function(){
        var select_val=$(this).val();
        if($(this).val()=='10'){
            $('li.todo').show();
        }else{
            $('li.todo').hide();
            $('li.todo').filter(function(){
                if($(this).attr('itemage')==select_val)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have to make static variables before change function to check the other drop down menu stat and select the list with depending selected item

Comment: With your current code it won't work. You need to rewrite the code that all changes to the filter execute 1 function only. In this function you need to check the states of your filter.

Comment: @chakrounyesser thanks..but what do you mean by static variables?

Comment: @A1rPun i'm abit new to jQuery..any direction as to how i can do this?

Comment: in mean varaible withou var before declration, i will write some code for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could trigger the handler of another event in your current handler by using `trigger()` method, the other option is combining the 2 handlers and listening to `click` event, if I have understood the question correctly something like the following should work:

```
$('.sort, .itemage').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this).hasClass('sort') 
                ? $(this).addClass('active') 
                : $('.sort.active');

    var itemage = $('.itemage').val(),
        b = itemage == 10;

    $('.sort').not($this).removeClass('active');

    if ($this.hasClass('showall')) {
        $('li.todo').hide().filter(function () {
            return (this.getAttribute('itemage') === itemage || b);
        }).show();
        return;
    }

    var sel = $this.hasClass('incomplete') 
              ? 'span.uncheck_box'
              : 'span.check_box';

    $('li.todo').hide().filter(function () {
        return (this.getAttribute('itemage') === itemage || b) 
               && !! $(this).find(sel).length;
    }).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5GWz/

Answer (score 0):

I Updated you [code](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/4H66K/8/) with "showall" and "complete" exemple, change `class="complete"` to `data-stat="complete"` to simplify detecting what we need.

There is many other method more useful for this filter style, but if you will have only two option, this will be simple to use too.